# can't send data from controller to view in a codeIgniter project

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to send data from my controller to the view. Here is how I do:
In the controller:

```
function getAllProjects() 
    {
      $where= array('id_user'=>$this->session->userdata('id_user'));
      $result=$this->expenses_model->get_all('projets', $where);//get_all returns an array
      echo json_encode ($result);
      return $result;
    }

function index (){
                       $data['all_projects']= $this->getAllProjects();
                       $this->session->set_userdata('id_user', 28);
                       $this->load->view('layout/public/header');
                       $this->load->view('content/public/profil/modules/expenses',$data);
                       $this->load->view('layout/public/footer');
                     }
```

echo json_encode $data  returns a correct result) in the controller but I don't know how to do to display it in the view. I tried:(in the view)

```
<label><strong>Sur le projet</strong></label>
       <select class="span4" id="projet" name="projet">
    <?php 
        if (isset($all_projects) && ! empty($all_projects))
            {  echo "there is some projects"; //is not printed
            foreach ($all_projects as $project){
            echo  "<option value=".$project['id_projet'].">".$project['titre']."</option>";   }
           else  {
                 echo "<option value='0'>No projects</option>";
                               }
```

But it does not show anything in the drop down list "projects"
 What I am doing wrong? Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Why are you using the deprecared `mysql_*` functions? CodeIgniter has a pretty good DB library. Why are you not using that instead?

Comment: What's the query returning exactly? Is it correctly formed? You might want to try and output that query and run it directly on your database to see what the result is -- it's most likely wrong somewhere, and therefore not returning any result. Although as @KemalFadillah said I would start by rewriting this to use CI's native DB classes.

Comment: The query returns a correct result that's why I kept on using "classic" DB queries. I'm newbie to codeIgniter, but my problem now is especially with how to send data correctly

Comment: do you get the value date_debut at the controller?

Comment: Yes I get the query result in the controller but not in the view

Comment: can you please provide a var_dump($data) printout just BEFORE you load the view?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange, var_dump($data) returns the first value of id_heure (actually the DB query must return 4 results)

Comment: can you please edit your question and post the var_dump so we can examine it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the foreach like this and it worked :

```
foreach ($all_projects as $project)
    {
            echo  "<option value=".$project->id_projet.">".$project->titre."</option>";
                                    }
```

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` returns a *resource* and you're handing that to `$this->load->view();` as the second parameter. If you dig into the underlying CodeIgniter source, you'll find that CodeIgniter does not know how to deal with Resources as this parameter - only Arrays and Objects.

Please refrain from using `mysql_query()` and it's friends. As per [PHP official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL
>   extension should be used.

More importantly than this, if you're using CodeIgniter on-top of PHP, use the [Database Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html) in conjunction with the [Active Record Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) to perform database queries. Hell, even use [Datamapper ORM](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/) - please don't use `mysql_query()` or friends.

Comment: I rewrote model's functions using CodeIgniter DB library and I edited my question. Could you please read what I have changed? Thanks